# Splash screen no ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Qual a forma mais fácil de fazer um Splash Screen no ios?
Sempre vejo tutoriais diferentes, e não consigo.
Eu quero apenas que carregue uma imagem por 3 segundos antes de entrar na minha aplicação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro utilizar Asset Catalogs. Ao criar um projeto, o XCode já cria um arquivo desses (Images.xcassets). Caso seu projeto não tenha, adicione um. Abra o arquivo e na lista da esquerda clique com o botão direito e selecione "New Launch Image".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então arraste as imagens para os dispositivos/resoluções que deseja suportar. Na view bem da direita (Utilities) você pode vericar o tamanho que cada uma das imagens deve ter (Expected Size).
Para finalizar, vá até a tela dos targets do projeto e selecione o asset LaunchImage como Launch Images Source.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A forma mais simples para aumentar o tempo de visibilidade da splash screen é fazer a thread main dormir. Exemplo:

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    sleep(3.0);
    return YES;
}`

Entretanto isso não é recomendado pela Apple pois o app deve estar disponível o mais rápido possível.

Comment: Fiz esse procedimento, e da erro ao compilar:he launch image set named "LaunchImage" did not have any applicable content."

Comment: Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Verifique se as imagens que você colocou são exatamente do tamanho esperado (selecione cada configuração e confira o campo "Expected Size")